# Why does moving forward switch the file system here?

Tags: filesystems, mount, file-descriptors

If I navigate to a new, empty directory

```
~$ cd "`mktemp -d`"
```

and mount a file system there

```
/tmp/tmp.4MlNzMERSw$ sudo mount /dev/sda5 .
```

and then try to list the files there, I don't see the files on this file system:

```
/tmp/tmp.4MlNzMERSw$ ll
total 8
drwx------  2 christoph christoph 4096 Jun 18 21:06 ./
drwxrwxrwt 18 root      root      4096 Jun 18 21:09 ../
```

My explanation for this is that the terminal acquires a file descriptor of `/tmp/tmp.4MlNzMERSw` when I execute the command in the first code block. This is confirmed by the fact that I can unmount the file system by executing

```
/tmp/tmp.4MlNzMERSw$ sudo umount .
```

in the same terminal windows, but if I open a new terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + N</kbd>, I can't. And I can't do so in the first terminal until I either close the second terminal or navigate away in it. Of course, I can't unmount it in the second terminal either as long as I stay in `/tmp/tmp.4MlNzMERSw` with it. The point is that it doesn't matter whether I move the first terminal away from `/tmp/tmp.4MlNzMERSw` as it seems to hold on to its old file descriptor (of what `/tmp/tmp.4MlNzMERSw` used to be) and doesn't acquire a new one (which would then keep the file system busy and prevent non-lazy unmounting).

Now I would not expect autocompletion of file names to work in the first terminal window but I would in the second one. And this is exactly what I observe. But afaik, autocompletion of file names is prefetched anyways, in some way, even though I can't find evidence for this (but evidence against it), at the moment.

However, what I don't understand is why I **can do** relative location changes forwards (like `cd mnt`) in the first terminal window **without** going back first (e.g. `cd ..` and then `cd tmp.4MlNzMERSw/mnt` or `cd tmp.4MlNzMERSw` + `cd mnt`).

The first terminal window apparently can use its existing file descriptor to list the contents of the directory as it was before the mounting happened. So why doesn't it use this same file descriptor to navigate forward?* Is this not possible?

* If it was doing this, the operation would obviously fail.

### My setup

My computer runs Ubuntu 16.04 with Linux 4.4.0 and the latest updates installed. I use the default terminal emulator (GNOME Terminal (version 3.18.3)) with bash 4.3.48:

```
$ /proc/self/exe --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ gnome-terminal --version
GNOME Terminal 3.18.3

$ uname -r
4.4.0-79-generic
```

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? What happens when you create a new window depends on how the terminal emulator decides which directory to start it in.

Comment: What do you mean by “moving forward”? As long as you're in the directory that's otherwise hidden behind the mount point, you can access the content of this directory, as long as you use relative paths. You seem to imply something different but your explanation is too fragmented to be comprehensible. Copy-paste a transcript of what you're doing.

Comment: @Gilles I stated the terminal emulator I'm using in the question: `gnome-terminal` By "moving forward", I mean to move to a subdirectory of the current location or to move further forward from there (recursive definition + transitivity ;-)). And yes, I imply something different and am about to comment about it below the existing answer.

Comment: This is some behaviour of your shell.  Please show the exact shell you're using e.g. `/proc/self/exe --version`.  (Unfortunately I can't seem to see the same behaviour on my system)

Comment: @sourcejedi I added this and more info to the question.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> /tmp/tmp.4MlNzMERSw$ sudo mount /dev/sda5 .
> ```

After doing this, `/dev/sda5` is mounted on `/tmp/tmp.4MlNzMERSw`. But the current directory of the shell is still the old `/tmp/tmp.4MlNzMERSw`, the one that's hidden behind the mount point.

> it seems to hold on to its old file descriptor (of what /tmp/tmp.4MlNzMERSw used to be) and doesn't acquire a new one

A process's current directory isn't a numbered file descriptor, but it behaves very much like a file descriptor. The current directory is a handle on the directory, not a string. The path initially used to reach the directory may no longer be valid, but that doesn't affect the validity of the file descriptor. A file descriptor keeps refering to the same file until it's closed. That shell process's current directory keeps being the subdirectory of `/tmp` until the shell emits a `chdir` system call.

You'd see something similar if you renamed the directory:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo
$ cd /tmp/foo
$ pwd
/tmp/foo
$ touch first
$ ls
first
$ mv /tmp/foo /tmp/bar
$ pwd
/tmp/foo
$ pwd -P
/tmp/bar
$ mkdir /tmp/foo
$ echo $PWD
/tmp/foo
$ ls
first
$ ls $PWD
$ cd $PWD
$ ls
```

The shell's current directory remains the old `/tmp/foo`, the one containing a file called `first`, until the `cd` command is called.

Comment: This is weird. I `mv`ed my working directory away and was still able to do relative path changes: https://pastebin.com/Vv3jcW8F To my surprise, I even was able to do this after I mounted something else in the current working directory: https://pastebin.com/nvYMfmue I then went ahead and created a directory with the same name as one that exists in the FS I was about to mount into the current working directory so see where I go when I go into this directory. Apparently, in this case, the terminal suddenly decides to go to the directory on the newly mounted FS: https://pastebin.com/esNsVAnJ

Comment: If it was the other way around, I'd understand it. Then, my expl. would be sth. like: "The terminal probably reads the directory contents of its current working directory or possible has already read them and just checks the list. It doesn't find anything and asks the OS about the location using the path, just to be sure (especially important if the directory entries were pre-read). It then is told about the new contents of the directory in this path." However, this doesn't work as it prefers to go forward in the newly mounted FS, not the old one. But it does either if only given 1 option.

Comment: @UTF-8 Without thinking much about it I don't understand what's going on in the third example. What shell are you using, what version? Can you reproduce it with no configuration file (`bash --norc`)? Run `strace -p1234` in another terminal where 1234 is the shell's PID to see what the shell is doing.

Comment: I added more details about my setup to the question. I can reproduce the phenomenon without configuration: https://pastebin.com/JmP1tA2i https://pastebin.com/gPt4sx93